# Table not being styled properly

Tags: html, css

I've got a table that I'm trying to style. I wanted to have a `bottom-border` underneath the `thead` and each `tr` but no matter what I put, it just won't apply. I even tried setting a color for the `thead` but that wouldn't give either. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.border-bottom {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #CCD5DE;
    }

    table {
     width: 100%;
     max-height: 500px;
     overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    thead {
     color: red;
    }
    
    th {
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 20px;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-align: left;
     
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    td {
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 18px;
     letter-spacing: .75px;
     text-align: left;
     
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="spaced-div">
  <table>
    <thead class="bottom-border">
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Fees</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="border-bottom">
        <td>March 21, 2020</td>
        <td>DMC</td>
        <td>1,330</td>
        <td>5.71</td>
        <td>23.54</td>
        <td>7,617.84</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major issues here,

**1)** Css property `border-collapse: collapse;` should be under `table` element like,

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**2)** Make sure you are having the same class name **.border-bottom** for both `thead` and `tbody tr` .

```css
.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CCD5DE;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
    color: red;
}

th {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: left;

    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .75px;
    text-align: left;

    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spaced-div">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="border-bottom">
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Fees</th>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="border-bottom">
          <td>March 21, 2020</td>
          <td>DMC</td>
          <td>1,330</td>
          <td>5.71</td>
          <td>23.54</td>
          <td>7,617.84</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```